# C# WebClient allow encrypted connection only

Tags: c#, .net

Here is a sample code of my app which uploads some data to server and reads response.
How can I tell if connection is secured? This code runs even if the link is encrypted or not (regardless of https prefix)

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{


    byte[] response = client.UploadValues("https://mytestserver.com", new NameValueCollection() { { "Abc", "def" } });

    result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
}
```

What I mean, is someone may run a web serwer on port 443 (https), but leave the connection not secured at all like "classic" port 80.

I have registered a ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback where I check the certificate signature, but obviously it is not being executed if there is no certificate at all.

Perfect situation for a MITM attack.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "regardless of https prefix". If it's https, it will be secure, surely? Could you clarify your question please?

Comment: Why not check if the url starts with https, and if it doesn't, throw an exception?

Comment: Please see my updated question

Comment: Still your question is not clear enough!

Comment: If someone runs a non-HTTPS server on port 443 and someone attempts to connect to that server with a URL starting `https` they will get an *error*, not HTTP running unencrypted.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not certificate and you want to visit HTTPS-URL just return true at your Callback method.That means the certificate is validated.

```
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```